# how to convert stringtype to int type in adf using variables

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

how to convert stringtype to int type in adf using variables , I have validate the rowcount before doing the copy activity

Comment: You should spend some time with the [Expressions and functions article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) and in particular the [Conversion functions section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#conversion-functions).

Answer (score 0):

@int(variable('rowcount')) .
Read more about this here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#int